# How to get the properties of the Details tab in a file

Tags: reflection, file, c#-3.0

You should all have noticed if you right click a file in the windows explorer, there is a tab named Details. Is there any trick to get these properties, and specifically the product name, whether this is a .NET file or not, over C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`FileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) class for that purpose.

```
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("Product name : {0}", fvi.ProductName);
```

Comment: Real nice, i haven't heard this class...so far..thanx dude. Problem is that this doesn't show anythiung on a .cab file :(

Comment: Neither does the Properties window ;)